# line.strip() method clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Language: python (Version: 3.7.3)
Proficiency: Novice**

I want to remove all the leading and trailing spaces in each line of the file. Therefore I have used the in-build method 'strip()' which does the job almost but my code started inaction from the bottom of the file which resulted in duplicating the lines in the file. Any assistance will be highly helpful to achieve the aim.

**My code as follows:**

```
class filecorrection:

    def removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile(self, fromFile):
        with open(fromFile, 'r+') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                file.write(line.strip() + "\n")

cm = filecorrection()
cm.removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile("filepath")
```

I tried to use seek method to bring the pointer at the beginning of the file but did not get the perfect output.

```
class filecorrection:

def removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile(self, fromFile):
    with open(fromFile, 'r+') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        **file.seek(0)**
        for line in lines:
            file.write(line.strip() + "\n")

cm = filecorrection()
cm.removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile("filepath")
```

**Expected:** (Removal of trailing and leading spaces)

```
<book id="bk105">
<author>Corets, Eva</author>
<title>The Sundered Grail</title>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<price>5.95</price>
<publish_date>testing</publish_date>
</book>
```

**Actual:**

```
  <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>testing</publish_date>
   </book><book id="bk105">
<author>Corets, Eva</author>
<title>The Sundered Grail</title>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>
<price>5.95</price>
<publish_date>testing</publish_date>
</book>
```

Comment: You don't need a class for this. `remove_leading_and_trailing_spaces_in_a_file` (note the preferred naming convention for methods) should just be a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file twice like so

```py
class filecorrection:

    def removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile(self, fromFile):
        lines = []

        with open(fromFile, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()

        with open(fromFile, "w") as file:
            for line in lines:
                file.write(line.strip() + "\n")

cm = filecorrection()
cm.removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile("test.xml")
```

instead of attempting to read and write to the file at the same time. Opening the file in write mode (`w`) will truncate the file to zero length and begin writing from the beginning.

Comment: Opening the file in `w` mode  will above all truncate it, not only set the pointer at the start, which the OP already tried by using `seek(0)`.

Comment: Writing in other file works as expected. However, any alternative to achieve the same in the same file?

Comment: @PrasadRajassekaran It's safer to write to a *separate* file first, and only replace the original after you know the complete write has succeeded, to avoid corrupting your original in the event of an error.

Comment: This will write over the top of the same file just like writing into a different file.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code:

- You are trying to write to the same input file.

Also try to use different variable for lines you read and the new lines you create. That's a good practice.

See updated code below.

```
with open(fromFile, 'r+') as infile, \
     open(writeFile, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                new_line = line.rstrip('\n').strip()

                #now write the new line to out file 
                outfile.write(new_line + "\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use another file to store the intermediate results and then replace the original file with it. Here you are reading and writing into same file.

```
import pathlib
import shutil

class filecorrection:

    def removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile(self, fromFile):
        parent_path=pathlib.Path(fromFile).parent

        # Make sure you have permissions to create a file. If not
        # you can save intermediate results in memory instead.
        temp_file = str(parent_path / "temp_file")
        with open(fromFile, 'r+') as file, open(temp_file, 'w+') as temp:
            for line in file:
                temp.write(line.strip()+"\n")

        shutil.move(temp_file, fromFile)

cm = filecorrection()
cm.removeLeadingandTrailingSpacesinaFile('file.txt')
```